# Filter design for audio signal

Tags: matlab, audio, filter, signal-processing, octave

What I am trying to do is simple. I have a few .wav files. I want to remove noise and filter out specific frequencies. I don't have matlab and I intend to write my own code for all the filters. 
Right now, I have a way to read the .wav file and dump out the structure into a text file. 
My questions are the following:

1. Can I directly apply the digital
   filters on this sampled data?{ ie,
   can I directly do a convolution
   between my input samples and h(n)
   for the filter function that i
   choose?).
2. How do I choose the
   number of coefficients for the
   Window function?

I have octave, so if someone can point me to anything that gives me some idea on how to process the .wav file using octave, that would be great too. I want to be able to filter out the frequency and then listen to the  sound again. Is this possible with octave?

I'm just a beginner with these kinds of things, so please bear with me if my questions are too naive. 
Any help will be great.

Comment: Have a look at the following blog post regarding the signal processing part http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2010/06/30/vuvuzela-denoising-with-parametric-equalizers/

Comment: Have a look at chapter 29 of the GNU Octave manual at http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/octave3/octave_256.html

Answer (score 3):

You can get `wavread` and `wavwrite` in `octave-audio` to do IO to .wav files.  There are functions for applying (`filter`) and visualizing (`freqz`, `impz`) in `octave-signal`.  Unfortunately I can't figure out the "right" way to get `fir1` and `butter` and `cheby` and friends.  You may have to get `octave-forge` by hand.

Answer (score 1):

That depends. You need to factor in the desired roll-off of the filter and the bandwidth of the filter amongst other factors. You also express the desire to filter out specific frequencies. This implies that you need one or more band-pass and/or band-reject filters. While FIR filters can be designed to handle these situations, you're better off with IIR (infinite impulse response) filters which have their own quirks.

I suggest you read up on digital filters to better understand what you're getting yourself into. They aren't particularly hard but it does involve a bit of mathematics.